# __security_init_cookie and PI

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I found this function in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\gs_support.c

1. `0xBB40E64E=3141592654=PI` - why is `DEFAULT_SECURITY_COOKIE` set to this value when the platform is not win64?
2. Why there are many exclusive OR calculation among `systemtime`, `ProcessId`, `ThreadId`, `TickCount`, etc.
3. What does the number 0x00002B992DDFA232 mean?

```
#ifdef _WIN64
#define DEFAULT_SECURITY_COOKIE 0x00002B992DDFA232
#else 
#define DEFAULT_SECURITY_COOKIE 0xBB40E64E
#endif

extern UINT_PTR __security_cookie;
extern UINT_PTR __security_cookie_complement;

typedef union {
    unsigned __int64 ft_scalar;
    FILETIME ft_struct;
} FT;
void __cdecl __security_init_cookie(void)
{
    UINT_PTR cookie;
    FT systime={0};
    LARGE_INTEGER perfctr;

    if (__security_cookie != DEFAULT_SECURITY_COOKIE
#if defined (_X86_)
        && (__security_cookie & 0xFFFF0000) != 0
#endif 
       )
    {
        __security_cookie_complement = ~__security_cookie;
        return;
    }


    GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&systime.ft_struct);
#if defined (_WIN64)
    cookie = systime.ft_scalar;
#else 
    cookie = systime.ft_struct.dwLowDateTime;
    cookie ^= systime.ft_struct.dwHighDateTime;
#endif
    cookie ^= GetCurrentProcessId();
    cookie ^= GetCurrentThreadId();
    cookie ^= GetTickCount();
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&perfctr);
#if defined (_WIN64)
    cookie ^= perfctr.QuadPart;
#else 
    cookie ^= perfctr.LowPart;
    cookie ^= perfctr.HighPart;
#endif
#if defined (_WIN64)

    cookie &= 0x0000FFFFffffFFFFi64;
#endif

    if (cookie == DEFAULT_SECURITY_COOKIE)
    {
        cookie = DEFAULT_SECURITY_COOKIE + 1;
    }
#if defined (_X86_)
    else if ((cookie & 0xFFFF0000) == 0)
    {
        cookie |= ( (cookie|0x4711) << 16);
    }
#endif
    __security_cookie = cookie;
    __security_cookie_complement = ~cookie;
}
```

Comment: this is called a "stack canary" and all the xor and stuff are to make it unique/unpredictable and change every time the program is ran. The default value doesn't have any meaning. it have some flaw (the value doesn't change if the program fork), but it's just a way to detect a stack corruption and not meant to be an unbreakable security fortress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Pi is a typical case of a ["Nothing up my sleeve number"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nothing_up_my_sleeve_number) which is common in security contexts. For security reasons using 0, 1 or any small number would be bad. But using a random number would be suspicious - is the number perhaps chosen to serve as an intentional backdoor?

Still if it's known that the security cookie is always 0xBB40E64E, exploit code may try to take advantage of the fact. Mixing in random other data makes it less predictable, and thus an even harder target to corrupt. (The goal of the cookie is to have a value on the stack that's known to the caller, but not to the exploit code).

No idea about the 64 bit value.

Answer (score 0):

0x00002B992DDFA232 is 3141592653589793241 >> 16

Comment: You answered the only 1/3 of the question.